# Query nested JSON with LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "rooms": [
    {
      "roomId": 1,
      "lightsPreset": [
        {
          "lightsPresetId": 1,
          "loadValues": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
        }, 
        {
          "lightsPresetId": 2,
          "loadValues": [ 11, 12, 13 ]
        }]
    },
    {
      "roomId": 2,
      "lightsPreset": [
        {
          "lightsPresetId": 1,
          "loadValues": [ 21, 22, 23 ]
        }, 
        {
          "lightsPresetId": 2,
          "loadValues": [ 211, 212, 213 ]
        }]
    }
  ]
}
```

and I need to get loadValues out of it (say roomId = 1 and lightsPresetId = 1)

I managed to do it using JSONPath

```
IEnumerable<JToken> loadValues = o.SelectTokens("$.rooms[?(@.roomId == 1)].lightsPreset[?(@.lightsPresetId == 1)].loadValues[*]");
```

but my goal is to make it work in .Net Framework 3.5 where JSONPath didn't work.

Trying this with LINQ gives me everything for roomId = 1, but I can't figure out how to query nested arrays.

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(rawJson);
var itemList = from values in o["rooms"].Children()
where (decimal)values["roomId"] == 1
select values;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Paste it into QuickType.io. Read the comment in the generated classes. Use the generated classes in your code with LINQ e.g. `root.Rooms.Where(r => r.RoomId == 1 && r.LightsPresets.Any(lp => lp.LightPresetId == 1)).Select(r => r.LightsPresets.First(lp => lp.LightsPresetId == 1).LoadValues)`

Comment: (or if roomId/lightPresetId is unique `root.Rooms.First(r => r.RoomId == 1).LightsPresets.First(lp => lp.LightsPresetId == 1).LoadValues`) - swap for FirstOrDefault if the id won't definitely exist, and use `?.` to access members

Comment: Second option worked just fine! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a PC now, so I can post it up as an answer rather than comment from the phone

If you visit https://quicktype.io you can use it to generate classes from your JSON:

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using SomeNamespace;
//
//    var someRootClassName = SomeRootClassName.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class SomeRootClassName
    {
        [JsonProperty("rooms")]
        public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Room
    {
        [JsonProperty("roomId")]
        public long RoomId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lightsPreset")]
        public List<LightsPreset> LightsPresets { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class LightsPreset
    {
        [JsonProperty("lightsPresetId")]
        public long LightsPresetId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("loadValues")]
        public List<long> LoadValues { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class SomeRootClassName
    {
        public static SomeRootClassName FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeRootClassName>(json, SomeNamespace.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this SomeRootClassName self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, SomeNamespace.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can convert your JSON to objects like this:

```
var root = SomeRootClassName.FromJson(rawJson);
```

And you can query it like:

```
var array = root.Rooms.First(r => r.RoomId == 1).LightsPresets.First(lp => lp.LightsPresetId == 1).LoadValues;
```

Or if those IDs might not exist:

```
var array = root.Rooms.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoomId == 1)?.LightsPresets.First(lp => lp.LightsPresetId == 1)?.LoadValues;
if(array != null) ....
```

When working with LINQ, it helps to make sure that anything that is a collection/array has a plural name. Then you can easily know whether you can just access a property of it (if it's singular) or have to use some method like First, Last, Single, Any, Where etc, if it has a plural name:

```
root.Rooms                             //plural, collection
  .First(r => r.RoomId == 1)           //.First on a plural results in a singular, a room object
  .LightsPresets                       //access a plural property of the single room above
  .First(lp => lp.LightsPresetId == 1) //first lightpresent in many LightPresets in the room
  .LoadValues                          //plural again; it's an array. The LINQ query resolves to an array output
```

Give your lambda arguments sensible names too - don't use `x` for everything; i used `r` for "a room in the collection of rooms", and `lp` for "a lightpreset in the collection of lightpresets"

Comment: Thank you for good explanation! Very helpful.

Comment: You're most welcome. If you'd like to click the grey check mark next to the answe rto turn it green it will change the appearance of the question on the dashboard so that people know you're not still looking for an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var rooms = (JArray) JObject.Parse(json)["rooms"]; 

var roomId=1;
var lightsPresetId =1;

int[] values = rooms.Where(r => (int)r["roomId"] == roomId)
    .Select(r=> r["lightsPreset"]).FirstOrDefault() 
    .FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x["lightsPresetId"] == lightsPresetId)["loadValues"]
    .ToObject<int[]>().ToArray();
```